# Съезжают метки на столбчатой диаграмме

Tags: python, matplotlib, визуализация, seaborn

Строю столбчатую диаграмму (барплот) вот таким кодом:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
metki = [ '1. Показатель первой характеристики',    '2. Показатель второй характеристики',  '3. Показатель третьей характеристики',
          '4. Показатель четвертой характеристики', '5. Показатель пятой характеристики',   '6. Показатель шестой характеристики',  '7. Показатель седьмой характеристики',
          '8. Показатель восьмой характеристики',   '9. Показатель девятой характеристики', '10. Показатель десятой характеристики',
          '11. Показатель одиннаддцатой характеристики',    '12. Показатель двенадцатой характеристики']
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
y=[16,3,4,11,16,0,23,1,21,7,14,19]
b = sns.color_palette("ch:start=.2,rot=-.3")
ax = sns.barplot(x=x,
                 y=y,
                 palette=["teal", "crimson"])
def without_hue(plot):
    for p in plot.patches:
        percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height()/30)
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2 - 0.05
        y = p.get_y() + p.get_height() +0.5
        ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y), size = 12)
kwargs = {'alpha': 0.9, 'linestyle': '-', 'linewidth': 0.5, 'edgecolor': 'black'}
ax = sns.barplot(x=x, y=y,  palette=b, **kwargs)
plt.xticks(x, metki, rotation=90)

without_hue(ax)
[![plt.tight_layout()][1]][1]
plt.show()
```

Но у меня почему-то съезжают метки по оси Х: они должны находиться ровно под каждым столбцом, а уезжают куда-то вправо... Очевидно, я допускаю какую-то грубую ошибку, но ломаю голову все утро и не могу понять. Помогите, пожалуйста!

(А еще, если кто-то подскажет, как сделать, чтоб весь текст помещался на графике- тому большое спасибо! Увеличение размера фигуры не помогает)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что первому столбцу соответствует позиция **0**, а у вас `x` начинается с 1. при `x=[0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` все у вас будет в порядке.

Comment: А какой текст у вас не умещается? аннотации к столбцам?

Comment: Большое спасибо! Да, не умещаются как раз эти 12 аннотаций

Comment: А Вы не знаете, существует ли вообще способ центрировать текст относительно столбцов его концом? Чтоб при ротации в 45 градусов, например, он так сильно не смещался (визуально уходит как будто в другой столбец)

Comment: насчет того, чтобы аннотации помещались внутри холста, самый простой способ - расширить лимиты по осям. например: `ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[0],ax.get_ylim()[1]+ax.get_ylim()[1]/5)`

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал всё-таки подсократить надписи. Неужели там весь этот текст в каждой надписи нужен? )  А если от длинных надписей никуда не деться, то можно горизонтальную ориентацию у баров сделать, тогда длинные надписи будут более нормально смотреться. Но тогда подписи с процентами будут выглядеть не очень, правда.

Comment: Да, спасибо за совет! Пока выравниваю их вручную: вместо тех значений x, которые у меня написаны в коде, использую эти: [-0.2,0.7,1.7,2.7,3.7,4.7,5.7,6.7,7.7,8.4,9.6,10.6]. Для того текста, с которым работаю сейчас, подходит: все выравнивается. Грустно, конечно, это вручную кастомизировать под каждый график постоянно, ну да ладно :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
metki = [ '1. Показатель первой характеристики',    '2. Показатель второй характеристики',  '3. Показатель третьей характеристики',
          '4. Показатель четвертой характеристики', '5. Показатель пятой характеристики',   '6. Показатель шестой характеристики',  '7. Показатель седьмой характеристики',
          '8. Показатель восьмой характеристики',   '9. Показатель девятой характеристики', '10. Показатель десятой характеристики',
          '11. Показатель одиннаддцатой характеристики',    '12. Показатель двенадцатой характеристики']
#x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
x=[0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
y=[16,3,4,11,16,0,23,1,21,7,14,19]
b = sns.color_palette("ch:start=.2,rot=-.3")
ax = sns.barplot(x=x,
                 y=y,
                 palette=["teal", "crimson"])
def without_hue(plot):
    for p in plot.patches:
        percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height()/30)
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2 - 0.05
        y = p.get_y() + p.get_height() +0.5
        ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y), size = 12)
kwargs = {'alpha': 0.9, 'linestyle': '-', 'linewidth': 0.5, 'edgecolor': 'black'}
ax = sns.barplot(x=x, y=y,  palette=b, **kwargs)
#plt.xticks(x, metki, rotation=60) #<--- убираем
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[0],ax.get_ylim()[1]+ax.get_ylim()[1]/5)
print(ax.get_ylim())
without_hue(ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(metki, rotation=40, ha="right") # <-- добавляем и выставляем ha (hirozintal alignment)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

Горизонтальный вариант для разнообразия:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
metki = [ '1. Показатель первой характеристики',    '2. Показатель второй характеристики',  '3. Показатель третьей характеристики',
          '4. Показатель четвертой характеристики', '5. Показатель пятой характеристики',   '6. Показатель шестой характеристики',  '7. Показатель седьмой характеристики',
          '8. Показатель восьмой характеристики',   '9. Показатель девятой характеристики', '10. Показатель десятой характеристики',
          '11. Показатель одиннаддцатой характеристики',    '12. Показатель двенадцатой характеристики']
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
y=[16,3,4,11,16,0,23,1,21,7,14,19]

df = pd.DataFrame({'m': metki, 'x': x, 'y': y})

def without_hue(plot):
    for p in plot.patches:
        percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_width()/30)
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() + 0.2
        y = p.get_y()  +0.5
        ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y), size = 12)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
b = sns.color_palette("ch:start=.2,rot=-.3")
kwargs = {'alpha': 0.9, 'linestyle': '-', 'linewidth': 0.5, 'edgecolor': 'black'}
ax = sns.barplot(x='y', y='m', data=df, palette=b, **kwargs);
without_hue(ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо! Да, иногда такие тоже использую. Возможно, в этот раз стоит как раз им и воспользоваться.... ради читабельности текста